# How to streamline this process into our workflow?

Tags: development-process, qa-process

**Background:**
We are a software as a service company, focusing on education sector. Lately, we decided to have a meeting that involves all Devs/qa to go through each ticket in our upcoming sprint and pool together ideas such as

- where this ticket can go wrong?
- which code base it impacts the most?
- what are some potential edgy cases?
- what bugs have we discovered in the past related to the ticket under discussion?

I am thinking of compiling a list of all previously discovered bugs and categorise them based on:

- which feature a bug is raised against?
- which version of API it is raised against?
- which customer reports it?

So when we have a discussion on a given ticket, we can easily relate this ticket to previously raised bugs.

I am going through Jira and pulling bug tickets into a Google spreadsheet atm, for a starter.

- People will have to do a manual search and look for tickets that are related to a feature.

I am wondering how we can streamline this process into our workflow, making it more accessible and easier to use.

Any suggestions? Is there a better tool to use?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish it would to be "more accessible and easier to use"?

Comment: @JoãoFarias, everything is in the early stage atm. Another way to put it is: if I was a dev, how easily I would pull out relevant bugs related to the feature I am about to work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on many factors like what process you follow are you in Agile , etc.

The most recommended way to make this process easy is to ensure tagging (Labeling) bugs to features and userstories ,

Lets say you identified a bug login not working. You can add this bug a tag with the userstory or feature ID that was added to create login feature.

So next time when you search the items that have label of userstory ID , you gets only the related bugs

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/add-remove-and-search-for-labels-136419.html

Check this also :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXXP3Qhi0qA

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that my team did not like my idea. So I will have to abandon it.